# What is the rate constant k for the reaction between potassium manganate and oxalic acid?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, kinetics, catalysis

For my school's chemistry classes, I am investigating the kinetics of the redox reaction between $\ce{K2MnO4}$ and $\ce{C2H2O4}$. I analyzed the data using a colorimeter set to $\pu{565nm}$. underneath are my results:
[image]

This picture shows the different results I obtained at different temperatures. Since absorption is directly related to concentration, I tried to take $\mathrm{ln(a)}$ over time and $\frac{1}{a}$ over time to determine the order of reaction and thus the rate constant k (by using the gradient of the straight line. however, none of the above resulted in a straight line as shown below. [image: lna]
[image: 1/a]

As you can see, neither of these lines are straight and therefore I cannot find rate constant k. Is it because the reaction is auto-catalytic? If so, can someone please explain how to find the rate constant?

Comment: Are you sure that you have used potassium manganate $\ce{K2MnO4}$ and oxalic acid ? Because potassium manganate is a green substance that is stable in basic solution, and oxalic acid does not exist in basic solution : it is transformed in oxalate ion. So I suspect you have worked in acidic solution with potassium permanganate $\ce{KMnO4}$ which is purple in solution.

Comment: What is series $1$, series $2$, and series $3 $? What do you report in figure $2$ and $3$ ? Versus what ?

Comment: @Maurice I used manganate, a green substance which I then dissolved in water for a 0.001M purple solution. then I added 0.1M oxalic acid and placed it in a colorimeter.

Comment: @Maurice the series 1, 2 and 3 can be ignored, it's just excel placing it in. and for the second chart it is ln(absorbance) vs. time and the third is 1/absorbance vs. time.

Comment: Why did you choose potassium manganate ? it is not a good choice. Because, even without oxalic acid, potassium manganate gets slowly decomposed in water, due to the acidity of atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$ producing $\ce{MnO2 + KMnO4}$ $$\ce{3 K2MnO4 + 2 CO2  -> 2 KMnO4 + MnO2 + 2 K2CO3}$$

Comment: @Maurice Sounds about right, but I don't see how this is a problem. The reaction can also be carried out with permanganate just fine. My question is how to find the rate constant for the reaction shown in the first image. To clarify, I am studying the effects of autocatalysis on rate of reaction, and I want to use the Arrhenius equation for find the activation energy, but I have no clue how to find rate constant k.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126553/discussion-between-clau-and-maurice).